# Filter array using includes with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

I'm trying to filter an array of objects using the `includes` method but I think I'm doing something wrong. Could someone help me?
It doesn't need to be an include method but it must return objects as the example below:

```
<html>
<script>
const testeArray = [{name:"antonio", category: ["One","Two"]},{name:"joana", category: ["Two"]}];
const catArray1 = ["One","Two"];
const catArray2 = ["One"];
const text = "an"

const resultArray1 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.includes(catArray1);
})  
console.log(resultArray1);  //should return antonio and joana objects

const resultArray2 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.includes(catArray2);
})  
console.log(resultArray2);   //should return antonio object only 

</script>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<script>
const testeArray = [{name:"antonio", category: ["One","Two"]},{name:"joana", category: ["Two"]}];
const catArray1 = ["One","Two"];
const catArray2 = ["One"];
const text = "an"

const resultArray1 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.includes(catArray1);
})  
console.log(resultArray1);  //should return antonio and joana objects

const resultArray2 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.includes(catArray2);
})  
console.log(resultArray2);   //should return antonio object only 

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#some` along with `Array#includes` to check if one array contains any of the elements of another array.

```js
const testeArray = [{name:"antonio", category: ["One","Two"]},{name:"joana", category: ["Two"]}];
const catArray1 = ["One","Two"];
const catArray2 = ["One"];
const text = "an"

const resultArray1 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.some(x => catArray1.includes(x));
})  
console.log(resultArray1);  //should return antonio and joana objects

const resultArray2 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.some(x => catArray2.includes(x));
})  
console.log(resultArray2);   //should return antonio object only
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the item category and check if returned array length is greater than 0.

```html
<html>
<script>
const testeArray = [{name:"antonio", category: ["One","Two"]},{name:"joana", category: ["Two"]}];
const catArray1 = ["One","Two"];
const catArray2 = ["One"];
const text = "an"

const resultArray1 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.filter(cat => catArray1.indexOf(cat) > -1).length > 0;
})  
console.log(resultArray1);  //should return antonio and joana objects

const resultArray2 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
return item.name.includes(text) && item.category.filter(cat => catArray2.indexOf(cat) > -1).length > 0;
})  
console.log(resultArray2);   //should return antonio object only 

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an exact match, you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert array to string and use `===` operator for matching.

```
const testeArray = [{name:"antonio", category: ["One","Two"]},{name:"joana", category: ["Two"]}];
const catArray1 = ["One","Two"];
const catArray2 = ["One"];
const text = "an"

const resultArray1 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
    return item.name.includes(text) && JSON.stringify(item.category) === JSON.stringify(catArray1);
})  
console.log(resultArray1);  //should return      antonio and joana objects

const resultArray2 = testeArray.filter((item)=>{
    return item.name.includes(text) && JSON.stringify(item.category) === JSON.stringify(catArray2);
})  
console.log(resultArray2);
```

This will work when elements are in same position for both arrays.